# Integrate Azure AD B2C with Xamarin App

Tags: azure, xamarin, azure-ad-b2c

My Xamarin App (PCL) calls a Web API as shown in the code below:

```cs
AuthenticationResult ar = await new AuthHelper().AcquireTokenSilentAsync();
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Settings.ApiUrl);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", ar.Token);
    using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/job"))
    {
         response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
         using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
         {
             string result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
             return result != null ? JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<JobTask>>(result) : null;
         }
     }
}
```

My Web API is authorized as follows:

```cs
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin,BusinessAdmin")]
```

I am using Azure AD B2C to obtain the token. I am able to get the user roles from Azure AD Graph. What I am unsure about is how to add the roles that are returned from the Graph query into the `AuthenticationResult.Token` that gets passed to the Web API.

Answer (score 0):

**Azure AD B2C does not currently have first class support for application roles nor groups as claims in the token**.

You can request this feature in the [Azure AD B2C Feedback Forum](http://aka.ms/aadb2cuv)

Alternatively, **you can implement this yourself via [Custom Policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-overview-custom)**. To do this you would add a step in your User Journey that calls out to the Graph to obtain either of these and adds them as claims to the token. See [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-rest-api-step-custom) for more info.